# NSUserDefaults - how to set start value?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I am making sounds enabled UserDefaults, I am managing then good and it works then I set YES/NO values.

```
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:kSoundEnabled];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

How to set YES sound parameter for first app run and where can I do it?

Comment: why not just check [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kSoundEnabled] == nil and set your local variable to YES?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set initial values using `registerDefaults:` which takes an `NSDictionary` of all your initial keys and their respective values. Example:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:@{ kSoundEnabled : @YES }];
```

Comment: ... which is implemented in a nice way: registered defaults aren't stored to disk, just checked in memory if nothing is stored. So you can change those defaults freely whenever you want with no legacy issues.

Answer (score 0):

In your application delegate (usually `AppDelegate.m` ) do

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
   NSUserDefaults* userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   if([userDefaults objectForKey:kSoundEnabled] == nil) {
      [userDefaults setObject:@YES forKey:kSoundEnabled];
      [userDefaults synchronize];
   }
}
```

Comment: It MUCH better to use `NSUserDefaults registerDefaults:`.

Comment: @rmaddy, why do you think so?

Comment: @user3358463 Because that is its purpose. It is there to setup default values without the need to check for `nil` or to write initial values. Once the defaults are registered, you don't need any special logic in any of your code to check to see if there is a value or not for a given key. You simply get a value and act accordingly. It's much cleaner.

Comment: @rmaddy, aha, I read that code in that answer is better then registerDefaults, all right ,)

Comment: @user3358463 No, I was telling XeNoN that it is better to use `registerDefaults:` than the code in their answer.